# Given $a,b,c,d>0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$, prove $a+b+c+d\ge a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math, substitution, uvw

> Given $a,b,c,d>0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$, prove  $$a+b+c+d\ge a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd$$

The inequality can be written in the condensed form
$$\sum\limits_{Sym}a\ge\sum\limits_{Sym}a^3+\sum\limits_{Sym}ab$$

I was told that this is a pretty inequality to prove, but I have been unable to do so.

I've tried naive things like multiplying both sides by $a+b+c+d$, and rewriting $(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$, but nothing panned out (and the computations were relatively time-consuming). I also tried looking for clever applications of Cauchy-Schwarz (which seems like the way to go) and AM-GM, but nothing sprung out at me.

Comment: Cancelling $\sum\limits_{Sym}a^3$ in $\left(\sum\limits_{Sym}a^2\right)\left(\sum\limits_{Sym}a\right)\ge \sum\limits_{Sym}a^3 +\sum\limits_{Sym}ab$, then squaring and multiplying RHS by $\sum\limits_{Sym}a^2$ again, leads to a homogenius form: $2\sum\limits_{Sym}a^3b^3+3\sum\limits_{Sym}a^2b^2c^2\ge 6\sum\limits_{Sym}a^3bcd$, but doesn't help much though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a+b+c+d=4u$, $ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd=6v^2$ and $abc+abd+acd+bcd=4w^3$.

Hence, $16u^2-12v^2=1$ and our inequality is equivalent to $3v^6-4uv^2w^3+w^6\geq0$.

By Roll's theorem there are $x>0$, $y>0$ and $z>0$, for which

$x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

After this substitution we need to prove that

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^3y^3-x^3y^2z-x^3z^2y+x^2y^2z^2)\geq0$, which is Schur.

Comment: Oh man, lots of jumps, still, this is amazing....+1

Answer (score 2):

I got some hints from Crux Problem 3059, click [**here**](http://woobiola.net/math/crux/crux3059.htm) for more details=)

Based on the hints (which tries to relate the inequality with a constrained optimization problem), I worked out a proof as follows:

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c+d)^2=&\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd\\
=&\frac{1}{2}+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd
\end{align}
by assumption. Thus, in order to prove the inequality, it is equivalent to prove
$$
a+b+c+d\geq a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c+d)^2-\frac{1}{2}.
$$
This can further be simplified as proving
$$
a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c+d-1)^2\leq1.~~~~(*)
$$
Now we try to maximize the LHS under the constraint, i.e.
\begin{align}
\max&~~f\triangleq a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c+d-1)^2\\
s.t.&~~a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1.
\end{align}
Now we try to use the Lagrangian multiplier method. Let
$$
L=f+\lambda(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-1).
$$
Take the derivative of $L$ regarding $a,b,c,d$ respectively and let the derivative equal to $0$ gives the following set of equations:
\begin{align}
L_a=&a+b+c+d+3a^2+2a\lambda=1\\
L_b=&a+b+c+d+3b^2+2b\lambda=1\\
L_c=&a+b+c+d+3c^2+2c\lambda=1\\
L_d=&a+b+c+d+3d^2+2d\lambda=1,
\end{align}

Notice that these four equations share exactly the same form. Thus, either
$$
3x^2+2\lambda x=0,~~x=a,b,c,d,~~~~(case1)
$$
or
$$
a=b=c=d.~~~~(case2)
$$
We analyse these two cases separately:

Case 1:
Under this case, we have
$$
a+b+c+d=1.
$$
Since
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1,
$$
the only possibility is one of four elements $a,b,c,d$ equal to $1$ and others are all $0$, which gives $\lambda=-3/2$ and $f=1$.

Case 2:
By the assumption
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1,
$$
it follows
$$
a=b=c=d=\frac{1}{2},
$$
which gives $\lambda=-7/4$ and $f=1$.

Above all we have the maximum of $f$ is $1$ and this proves $(*)$.

Answer (score 2):

instead of solving this problem let's solve a simpler version of it :

Given a,b>0 and a^2+b^2=1, prove

a+b≥a^3+b^3+ab

you need to use what you have been given :

we know a^2 + b^2 = 1

adding 2ab to both sides of equation we have :

a^2 +b^2 + 2ab = 1 + 2ab

then :

(a+b)^2 = 1 + 2ab (1)

what we need to prove is that

a+b≥a^3+b^3+ab (2)

by adding 3a^2b + 3ab^2 to the both sides of (2) we have :

a + b + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 ≥ a^3 + b^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + ab (2)

(3ab+1)(a+b) ≥ (a+b)^3 +ab

using (1) we have

(3ab+1)(a+b) ≥ (2ab+1)(a+b) +ab

(ab)(a+b) ≥ ab

a+b ≥ 0

true statement based on assumption

so

a+b≥a^3+b^3+ab

we can use the same procedure to solve the original problem in the case that :

a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1   (1)

and then try to turn it to an equation which is simpler and easier to use in

equation below

a+b+c+d≥a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd  (2)

so by adding 2ab +2ac + 2cd + 2ad + 2bc + 2bd we turn (1) into

a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 + 2ab +2ac + 2cd + 2ad + 2bc + 2bd = 1 + 2ab +2ac + 2cd + 2ad + 
2bc + 2bd

(a+b+c+d)^2 = 1 + 2ab +2ac + 2cd + 2ad + 2bc + 2bd (3)

then we use equation (3) to simplify equation (2)

a+b+c+d
+ a*b^2 + a*c^2 + a*d^2 + 2a^2b +2a^2c + 2acd + 2a^2d + 2abc + 
ba^2+bc^2+bd^2 + 2ab^2 +2abc + 2bcd + 2abd + 2b^2c + 2b^2d+
ca^2+cb^2+cd^2 + 2abc +2ac^2 + 2c^2d + 2acd + 2bc^2 + 2bcd+
da^2+db^2+dc^2+ 2abd +2acd + 2cd^2 + 2ad^2 + 2bcd + 2bd^2
≥ 
a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd +

a*b^2 + a*c^2 + a*d^2 + 2a^2b +2a^2c + 2acd + 2a^2d + 2abc +

ba^2+bc^2+bd^2 + 2ab^2 +2abc + 2bcd + 2abd + 2b^2c + 2b^2d+

ca^2+cb^2+cd^2 + 2abc +2ac^2 + 2c^2d + 2acd + 2bc^2 + 2bcd+

da^2+db^2+dc^2+ 2abd +2acd + 2cd^2 + 2ad^2 + 2bcd + 2bd^2 =

(a+b+c+d)^3 +ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd =

(1 + 2ab +2ac + 2cd + 2ad + 2bc + 2bd ) ( a+b+c+d) +ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd =

a + 2a^2b + 2a^2c + 2acd + 2a^2d + 2abc + 2abd +

b + 2ab^2 +2abc + 2bcd + 2abd + 2b^2c + 2b^2d+

c + 2abc +2ac^2 + 2c^2d + 2acd + 2bc^2 + 2bcd+

d + 2abd +2acd + 2cd^2 + 2ad^2 + 2bcd + 2bd^2+

+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd

a+b+c+d

- a*b^2 + a*c^2 + a*d^2 + 2a^2b +2a^2c + 2acd + 2a^2d + 2abc +

ba^2+bc^2+bd^2 + 2ab^2 +2abc + 2bcd + 2abd + 2b^2c + 2b^2d+

ca^2+cb^2+cd^2 + 2abc +2ac^2 + 2c^2d + 2acd + 2bc^2 + 2bcd+

da^2+db^2+dc^2+ 2abd +2acd + 2cd^2 + 2ad^2 + 2bcd + 2bd^2≥

a + 2a^2b + 2a^2c + 2acd + 2a^2d + 2abc + 2abd +

b + 2ab^2 +2abc + 2bcd + 2abd + 2b^2c + 2b^2d+

c + 2abc +2ac^2 + 2c^2d + 2acd + 2bc^2 + 2bcd+

d + 2abd +2acd + 2cd^2 + 2ad^2 + 2bcd + 2bd^2+

+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd

after simplifying we reach to a true statement

Comment: This is an attempt to answer, no?

Comment: Please [see this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some information on how to format your posts using math tags. Right now your post is a bit hard to read.

Comment: Yes it is. a method has been shown to prove the case with two variables same method works for four variables.